# backbone.js isn't working on Android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, backbone.js

I've been developing an application using phonegap and backbone.js
it's working okay on iphone and Android (higher than 2.3) but with 2.3 it stops when creating the mainview using backbone.view.extend.

```
alert("before calling mainview");
  var mainView = new Bkam.mainView();
  alert("After calling mainview, before mainview.render");
```

the first alert is done correctly, while the second alert doesn't even show.

part of mainView function:

```
Bkam.mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    alert("INITIALIZING MAINVIEW");
  },
  //the rest of function
```

the alert inside the initialize doesn't show either.

This happens only with Android 2.3, all the alerts show on Android 4 and iphone.

any suggestion?

Comment: try adding some exception handling `try / catch` around the part that's not working (and just show an alert in the catch with the error). It's possible that it's using some functionality that isn't working on the older Android browser.

Comment: I did and I got this error : "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Have you tried the PhoneGap API for alert, like: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Comment: this is what I did:       try{
        var mainView = new Bkam.mainView();
      }
        catch(err){
        alert(err.message);
      }

Comment: the alert shows with the error "undefined is not a function".

Comment: The docs for phonegap show that it should be like this: navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])